# Using for statement, join each line in 2 lists and store in variable

Tags: python-2.7

```
a = [['gigethernet1/0/1', 234], ['vlan1', 675876], ['fastethernet1/0', 3534]]

b = [['gigethernet1/0/1', 78678], ['vlan1', 6789679687], ['fastethernet1/0', 67896786]]

anewlist = [line for line in a if "thernet" in line[0]]

bnewlist = [line for line in b if "thernet" in line[0]]
```

I have 2 variables with multiple lists. In variable A I am creating a new variable that filters specific lines with a certain string.'thernet' For variable B I am doing the same thing. I want to merge variables A and B together for each line but only include 1 element of variable B, see desired output below.

['gigethernet1/0/1', 234, 78678] 
['fastethernet1/0', 3534, 67896786]

Comment: Can you be more clear on your requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = [dict(anewlist), dict(bnewlist)]  #Create a list of dicts
    # dict([['a','b'],['c','d']]) => {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}

output = [[key]+[d.get(key) for d in data] for key in set().union(*data)]
    # '*' operator unpacks the list of dicts. Google 'python unpacking lists' for more info
    # set().union(dicts) create a set() of keys of the dicts passed in. Read about python sets, especially its `union` method,  and what happens when a dict is passed as an argument to `set()`.
    # Rest are list comprehension and dictionary operations!
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: worked perfectly. can you elaborate on how this works or point me in a direction so I can read up? Thank you so much by the way!

Comment: Thanks for elaborating I will study up on this to understand.